# PHP Array syntax and operation clarification

Tags: php, arrays

I have to convert a function from PHP to Java, and can use some clarification on PHP's array syntax, which has a few differences from Java.  The PHP code is

```
$W; //array defined before and has values
$S = array();
$j = wsnum - 1; //integer value here

for ( ;  ; ){
  $S[] = $j
  $S[] = $W[$j]; 

}
```

My interpretation of this snippet is

1. `$S` is initialized as an array of length 0
2. `$j` is pushed to `$S[0]`
3. The contents of `$W[$j]` are pushed to `$S[1]`

Is my interpretation correct, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is totally correct.

You can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) to learn more about php operators.

The `[]` operator is a "push" operator. Which always put the value assigned at the end of a given array.